# Relation (symmetric/reflexive/ transitive)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

let $R$ is a relation such that $R = \{(a,b) \in \Bbb Z_+^2: a \vert (b+1)\}$. Is this relation symmetric, reflexive and transitive?

The only problem i am facing is proving whether is it symmetric or not?
this is what i am doing..

if $a\vert(b+1)$, then $b+1 = ka$ where $k$ is a constant.

And now i have to prove that $b\vert(a+1)$ which can be written as $a+1 = qb$ where $q$ is a constant.

Now  am stuck what to do next. i considered $k$ and $q$ to be equals to $1$ just as an example which leads to  $a = b+1$ and $b = a+1$ which is absurd, so that means relation is not symmetric?

Comment: In order to show that $R$ is not symmetric, it is sufficient that you give at least one *example*, where symmetry fails. For instance, $(1,3)\in R$, but $(3,1)\notin R$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Lets consider an example (2,3) ∈ R and (3,2) ∈ R. i know that it is suffice to prove that the above relation is not symmetric by using a single example but (2,3) and (3,2) will make a difference in  deciding whether this relation is asymmetric and anti symmetric or not? So actually i am looking for generic method that would help me.  Thanking in advance

Comment: Ok, so now you also want to prove/disprove that the relation is antisymmetric? What is the difference between asymmetric and antisymmetric?

Generally speaking: In order to show that a relation obeys a rule, you need to *prove* it generally. In order to show that a relation does *not* obey a rule, just give one *counterexample*.

Comment: Antisymmetric means that the only way for both aRb and bRa to hold is if a=b. It can be reflexive, but it can't be symmetric for two distinct elements. So to summarize, Asymmetric relation is just one that is both Anti symmetric and Irreflexive. Just disproving that relation is not symmetric doesn't prove that the relation is asymmetric(anti symmetric is not possible since the relation is irreflexive).So according to you, i should ,rather than looking for a method to prove, look for a counterexample?

Comment: Ok, so asymmetric means, that whenever $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a)\notin R$.  Is this true for all $a,b$?
In addition, irreflexiv means, that $(a,a)\notin R$ for all $a$. Is this always true?

Comment: yes,this is true for all a,b

Comment: $(1,1)\in R$....

Comment: Thanks for identifying that pair. I just forgot that. So  that means this relation is none. But sir, looking for a counter example is an error prone method for me as depends on the question difficulty